# List negative indexing of 0; x[-0]

Tags: list, indexing

Can anyone explain how works Negative index of 0?

x = [2, 3, 5, 6]

print(x[-0])

**output:** 2

Comment: ``-0 == 0``....

Answer (score 1):

What you enter as the index gets evaluated. For example :

```
x = [2, 3, 5, 6]
print(x[2 - 1])
```

It prints `3` because it is evaluated as `print(x[1])`. Here you used `-0` so it is the same as `0`.